# PHP: What is the best way to get last even value in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose , I have a array with some integers value (odd and even both mixed) in php.and I want to get last even number.

Comment: Loop from last to first in the array and return the first even value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop that works backwards through the array would work.

```
$number=false;
$a=array(2,4,5,4,6,7,13,11,95,88,16,17,107);

for($i=count($a)-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    if( $a[$i] % 2 == 0 ){
        $number=$a[$i];
        break;
    }
}
echo $number; //16
```

Comment: While they did ask specifically about integers you could use fmod instead of modulo to make it work with decimal values